# How $A=\{x_n:n\in \mathbb N\}$ is an infinite set?Can you explain the proof?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

[image]

Can you please explain the underlined arguments? How does it deduce that $A$ is infinite?
I understood that when $y\in X$. There is an $U\in \mathscr O$ such that $x\in U$(since $\mathscr O$ is an open cover for $X$). Since $U$ is open there is an open  ball $B_d(y,\epsilon)\subseteq U$. By Archimedean property I can deduce  $B_d(x,\frac{1}{n})\subseteq U, \forall n>N$ How $x_n\neq y$ and $A$ is infinite?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative argument. Assume that $A$ is finite. Then there must exist some $a \in A$ such that $x_n = a$ for infinitely many $n$. There exist $U \in \mathcal O$ such that $a \in U$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_d(a,\varepsilon) \subset U$. Take any $n$ such that $x_n = a$ and $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$. Then $B_d(x_n,\frac{1}{n}) \subset U$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

We have

- $B_d(x_n, \frac{1}{n}) ⊈ U$ for every $n$,
- $B_d(y, \frac{1}{n}) ⊆ U$ for every $n > N$.

Therefore, so $x_n ≠ y$ unless $n ≤ N$.

Comment: I don't understand your last line.

Comment: I have split the line into pieces. Which part you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Here, you prove that for each $y \in X$, there exists $N$ such that for $n > N$, one has $x_n \neq y$.

This is sufficient to ensure that $A$ is infinite.

Comment: I don't understand your argument. Can you explain how do you prove $A$ is infinite here?

Comment: Assume that $A$ is finite. Then denote by $y_1, ..., y_p$ the elements of $A$ : that means that each $x_n$ is equal to one of the $y_k$. For each $y_k$ you have an integer $N_k$ such that for all $n > N_k$, $x_n \neq y_k$. Now, consider $N = \max(N_1, ..., N_p) + 1$. By definition of the $N_k$, $x_N$ cannot be equal to one of the $y_k$. But it has to, because it belongs to $A$. Contradiction.